# Finding the $n$th derivative of $f(x) = e^{\sin(x)}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry, exponential-function

I have a function $$f(x) = e^{\sin(x)}$$ I want to expand it in a infinte series using Maclaurin's theorem and for that I need to know if the remainder term $$R_n = \frac{x^n}{n!}f^{(n)}(\theta x),\quad (0<\theta<1)\quad[\text{Lagrange's from}] $$ converges as $n \to \infty$ but for that I need to know the $f^{(n)}(x) = e^{\sin(x)}$ the $n$th derivative of exponential trigonometric function.

I know how to find $n$-th derivative of functions like $\sin(x)$ or $ e^{ax}$ where you can  see the pattern but I cant see anything in this function.

$$\begin{align}
f'(x) &= \phantom{-}e^{\sin(x)}\cos(x) \\
f''(x) &= -e^{\sin(x)}(\sin(x)-\cos^2(x)) \\
f'''(x) &= -e^{\sin(x)}\cos(x)(3\sin(x)-\cos(2x)+1) \\
f^{(4)}(x) &= \phantom{-}e^{\sin(x)}(3\sin^2(x)+(1-6\cos^2(x))\sin(x)+\cos^4(x)+4\cos^2(x))
\end{align}$$

How am I supposed to find the $n$th derivative of function like these?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Just a heads-up: You asked the basic idea of this question [earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4320812/409), and that version was closed for lack of context. Deleting-and-reposting is not the appropriate way to circumvent closure; rather, you *should have* edited the original question to add the context you've included here. In this case, there's no harm done, but keep this in mind for the future.

Comment: Sorry It's my first time using Math.SE I did'nt knew I was supposed to edit rather than make a new one. I will keep this in mind from know on.

Comment: You can get something with the Bell polynomials  in the Faa Di Bruno formula, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula). Basically, you've got a composition of the exponential and the sine i.e. $e^{\sin x} = exp \circ \sin(x)$, and the derivatives of both functions are quite well-known. [Bell's polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials) can be found here.

Comment: You can obtain a formula using Faà di Bruno's formula. In general, it is known that if the radius of convergence of the Maclaurin series of $f$ and $g$ is infinite, then the same is true for the Maclaurin series of $f \circ g$.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to write this function as the series of $e^{u}$, where $u=sin(x)$, and differentiate this series term by term. You will see the pattern if you compare it to some other known series. I hope this helps.